# Rails: collection_check_boxes to filter search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, checkbox, act-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to implement a search view which enables users to search other users based on keyword AND multiple checkboxes for their tags. I'm still trying to figure out how to place the `collection_check_boxes` right, so that view is rendered correctly. Here's what I have so far:

```
  <%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= collection_check_boxes :options, :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {multiple: true} %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search", :id => "query" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :style => "float:left;"%>
  <% end %>
```

Can you help me complete the view function above by making sure that, when a user clicks `search` `collection_check_boxes` will add something like `tag=tag1&tag2&tag3` to the url?

Answer (score 1):

I will try :)

Generally everything is OK. Only small correction, if you change this line:

```
    <%= collection_check_boxes :options, :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {multiple: true} %>
```

to this:

```
    <%= collection_check_boxes :tag, :ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {multiple: true} %>
```

after submitting request, in URL will be something like this:

```
&tag%5Bids%5D%5B%5D=&tag%5Bids%5D%5B%5D=3&tag%5Bids%5D%5B%5D=2&search=test
```

more human view:

```
&tag[ids][]=&tag[ids][]=3&tag[ids][]=2&search=test
```

and this is OK. It always look like this when sending an array. In this particular case I've checked two checkboxes (with id=2 and 3). I don't know why there is also empty element :), but this is not a problem. I think there is no way to get results exactly like `tag=tag1&tag2&tag3`

In your "users" model you can get to the params by (after submitting form):

```
params[:tag][:ids] - array of id (checked checkboxes)
params[:search] - search input value
```

If you want to have checked some checkboxes on start (or after submit), add to collection_check_boxes  additional parameter:

```
options = {:checked=>tag_ids}
```

and deliver in variable *tag_ids* array of checkboxes id (which should be checked). All the code looks like this:

```
<%if params.has_key?(:tag)%>
  <%tag_ids = params[:tag][:ids]%>
<%else%>
  <%tag_ids = Array.new%>
<%end%>

<%=form_tag drons_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%=collection_check_boxes :tag, :ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {multiple: true}, options = {:checked=>tag_ids}%>
  <%=text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search", :id => "query"%>
  <%=submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :style => "float:left;"%>
<%end %>
```